# Eclipse Editor Driving Me Crazy - Restore Editor Pane To Full Width

Tags: eclipse

Okay, all I want to do is to have the editor pane (with the code in it) to go back to filling up the normal amount of space. When I try to drag it back, I get some weird split pane configuration thing going on, and it only takes up a part of the space in the middle.

1. I have already tried Reset Perspective.
2. I have already tried Toggle Split Editor, both horizontally and vertically.
3. If I try to drag the width of the editor to fill up the rest of the space, it only goes like 80% of the way.

This is eclipse mars. I don't know how it got like this in the first place.

EDIT: Also, every time I try to open a new file, it opens up a new pane in one of the sidebars.

EDIT: Here's a video of me trying to fiddle around with it:
https://youtu.be/Jl6XNWW96Lc

[image: eclipse editor pane split]
[image: eclipse editor pane shrunk]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EUREKA, I FIXED IT!

1. I switched to another workspace that wasn't broken as hell.
2. I did File -> Switch Workspace -> Other...
3. I expanded "Copy Settings"
4. I checked "Workbench Layout"
5. I selected the broken ass workspace and hit "OK"
6. Voila! The broken workspace adapted the layout of the working one. Transplant successful.

Comment: Good job on finding the fix and posting solution

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. The thing is that Eclipse has one "main" panel which takes up all the available space and from what i can tell the bottom panel is your main (or is it the "outline" one?), i cant say for sure from the screen which one exactly

I resolved this by closing all tabs except for one, circle it around until i found the "main" panel and just rebuilt from there

Comment: How did you know which one was the main panel? I've been trying this for a good while but with no luck. Also, the bottom panel seems to be the main because that's where files are opening into. But I can't seem to place it anywhere effectively to solve the problem.

Comment: Like you said, where the files are opening into is a big clue, also its the only one that doesnt "offer" splitting the panel right away. I just closed everything, every panel. I guess that minimizing the panels helps moving them to where they are supposed to beand they should snap right back into place